# writing to data to excel

Tags: python, django, csv

I have data that I need to export to excel, I just don't know how to go about it, here's the view I'm using, I've commented out my attempts.A push to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

```
def month_end(request):
    """
    A simple view that will generate a month end report as a PDF response.

    """
    current_date = datetime.now()
    context = {}
    context['month'] = current_date.month
    context['year'] = current_date.year   
    context['company'] = 3

    if request.method == 'POST':        
        context['form'] = MonthEndForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)

        if context['form'].is_valid():             
            #from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
            #import ho.pisa as pisa

            context['month_no'] = int(context['form'].cleaned_data['month'])
            context['company'] = context['form'].cleaned_data['company']
            context['year'] = context['form'].cleaned_data['year']
            context['month'] = datetime(context['year'], context['month_no'], 1).strftime('%B')

            sql = '''SELECT "campaign_provider"."originator" as originator, "campaign_provider"."cost", 
                        "campaign_receivedmessage"."network_id", 
                        COUNT("campaign_provider"."originator") AS "originator_count",
                        "shortcode_network"."network"
                    FROM "campaign_receivedmessage" 
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN "shortcode_network" ON ("shortcode_network"."id" = "campaign_receivedmessage"."network_id")
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN "campaign_provider" ON ("campaign_receivedmessage"."provider_id" = "campaign_provider"."id") 
                    WHERE ("campaign_provider"."company_id" = %s  
                    AND EXTRACT('month' FROM "campaign_receivedmessage"."date_received") = %s)        
                    GROUP BY "campaign_provider"."originator", "campaign_provider"."cost", "campaign_receivedmessage"."network_id", "shortcode_network"."network"
                    ORDER BY "campaign_provider"."originator", "campaign_receivedmessage"."network_id" ASC
                    ''' % (context['company'].id, context['month_no'])            

            context['rec_messages']= []            
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            for row in data:
                dict = {}
                desc = cursor.description
                for (name, value) in zip(desc, row) :
                    dict[name[0]] = value           
                try:
                    dict['share'] = RevenueShare.objects.get(company=context['company'], priceband=dict['cost'], network=dict['network_id']).customer_share
                    dict['revenue'] = dict['originator_count'] * dict['share']
                except:
                    dict['share'] = 0
                    dict['revenue'] = 0  
                context['rec_messages'].append(dict)

            #context['rec_messages'] = ReceivedMessage.objects.filter(provider__company__id=context['company'].id, date_received__month=context['month_no'], date_received__year=context['year']).values('provider__originator', 'provider__cost', 'network').annotate(originator_count=Count('provider__originator')).order_by('provider__originator')
            context['ret_messages'] = SentMessage.objects.filter(campaign__providers__company__id=context['company'].id, date_sent__month=context['month_no'], date_sent__year=context['year']).values('campaign__title').annotate(campaign_count=Count('campaign__title')).order_by('campaign__title')
            context['revenue_share'] = RevenueShare.objects.filter(company=context['company'].id)
            context['total_rec'] = 0
            context['total_ret'] = 0
            context['total_value'] = 0
            context['total_cost'] = 0

            context['queries'] = connection.queries

            for message in context['rec_messages']:
                context['total_rec'] += message['originator_count']
                context['total_value'] += message['revenue']

            for message in context['ret_messages']:
                message['price'] = 0.175
                message['cost'] = message['campaign_count'] * message['price']
                context['total_ret'] += message['campaign_count']                
                context['total_cost'] += message['cost']

            context['total'] = context['total_value'] - context['total_cost']
            context['loaded_report'] = "yes"

            data.append((context['data']))
            data.append(('Orginator', 'cost', 'network_id', 'originator_count', 'network'))


            file_name = '%s' % ('reports')

            return generate_csv(file_name, data)

           #template_data = render_to_string('reports/month_end_pdf.html', RequestContext(request, context))

            #csv_data = StringIO.StringIO()    
            #csv_data.seek()

            #simple_report = ExcelReport()34
            #simple_report.addSheet("TestSimple")
            #simple_report.writeReport(csv_data)

            #response = HttpResponse(simple_report.writeReport(),mimetype='application/ms-excel')
            #response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=simple_test.xls'

           #return response
            return render_to_response('reports/month_end.html', RequestContext(request, context))
            #return render_to_response('reports/rfm_models.html', RequestContext(request, context))

            #template_data = render_to_string('reports/month_end_pdf.html', RequestContext(request, context))

            #pdf_data = StringIO.StringIO()    
            #pisa.CreatePDF(template_data, pdf_data, link_callback=fetch_resources)
            #pdf_data.seek(0)

            #response =  HttpResponse(pdf_data, mimetype='application/pdf')
            #response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s_%s_%s.pdf' % (context['company'].name.lower().replace(' ', '_'), context['month'].lower()[:3], context['year'])


    if 'form' not in context.keys():
        context['form'] = MonthEndForm(user=request.user, data=context)

    return render_to_response('reports/month_end.html', RequestContext(request, context))
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look to xlwt http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

Comment: In particular you may find the xlwt examples useful: https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/examples/ such as the simple.py example https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/examples/simple.py

Answer (score 4):

You could directly write CSV from MySQL records,

```
import csv
csv_writer = csv.writer(open(FILENAME,'w'), delimiter=',',quotechar="'")

data = cursor.fetchall()
for row in data:
    csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

Full example at

http://snipplr.com/view/11970/simple-csv-dump-script/

```
SELECTQ="SELECT * FROM category"
FILENAME="dump.csv"

import MySQLdb
import csv

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="sakila")
dump_writer = csv.writer(open(FILENAME,'w'), delimiter=',',quotechar="'")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute(SELECTQ)
result = cursor.fetchall()
for record in result:
    dump_writer.writerow(record)

db.close()
```

Comment: Small note: instead of `csv.writer(open(FILENAME,'w'), delimiter=',',quotechar="'")` you can use `csv.writer(open(FILENAME,'w'), dialect='excel')` which reads better